# formatting time axis in rbokeh

Tags: r, bokeh, rbokeh

I am trying to create a linechart with `rbokeh` where the x-axis is supposed to show a datetime variable.

Consider the following example:

```
data <- tibble(
  time = as.POSIXct(c("2019-08-27 08:15:00",
           "2019-08-27 10:30:00",
           "2019-08-27 12:45:00")),
  value = c(0.3, 0.6, 0.2)
)

figure(data = data) %>%
  ly_lines(x = time,
           y = value) %>%
  ly_points(x = time,
            y = value,
            hover = value) %>%
  x_axis(label = "Date"
         # number_formatter = "numeral", 
         # format = list(hours = "%d %B %Y")
  ) %>%
  y_axis(label = "Values", 
         number_formatter = "numeral",
         format = list(percent = "0 %")) %>% 
  y_range(dat = c(0, 1))
```

This produces the following plot:

[image]

Not only does this show the wrong values on the x-axis, they are also formatted in a very inconvenient way.
I have tried changing the format to a more appropriate way by using the `format` argument (that has been commented out in my example), but this only causes the plot to not even be created anymore.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code worked for me with the format argument. If you want the time included, I would use this:

```
figure(data = data) %>%
  ly_lines(x = time,
           y = value) %>%
  ly_points(x = time,
            y = value,
            hover = value) %>%
  x_axis(label = "Date",
          number_formatter = "numeral", 
          format = list(hours = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  ) %>%
  y_axis(label = "Values", 
         number_formatter = "numeral",
         format = list(percent = "0 %")) %>% 
  y_range(dat = c(0, 1)) %>%
  theme_axis("x", major_label_orientation = 45)
```

Comment: how strange, I just checked it again and the code does not execute if I remove the hashes to disable the comments.

Comment: Did you add the comma in after label = "Date"?